# Update Custom ListView Item

Tags: java, android

I have a listview that uses a customadapter based on the baseadapter. The listview populates ok using external data and I can pick up the click events and know which item has been selected.

I'm having a problem updating the clicked item's views, like TextView and ViewFlipper.

Do I have to update something via the listview or is it via the adapter. I've tried things like the following;

```
View test = (View)adapter.getView(pos, null, myListView);
ViewFlipper temp = (ViewFlipper)test.findViewById(R.id.flipholder);
temp.showNext();
TextView temp2 = (TextView)test.findViewById(R.id.filmtitle);
temp2.setText("Hello World");
```

Which results in the viewfliper flipping the first and third item or second and fourth and the text not updating at all.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern in getView:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        ViewHolder holder;

        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added the above to my getView in the adapter, but I'm not sure how I should be accessing the components. 

I've tried the following;                                                                                      
View test = (View)adapter.getView(pos, null, myListView);
ViewHolder test2 = (ViewHolder)test.getTag();
test2.text.setText("Hello World");
test2.flipper.showNext();

Comment: I not sure you should be calling adapter.getView like that. That method is what is called to render the view. Can't you supply the data to the adapter as an array so that inside the adapter all the data is present?

Comment: Updating the text by updating the array in the adapter and calling notifyDataSetChanged on the listview works, but how do I update other views like the ViewFlipper I have in the listview item?

Comment: create a custom constructor  or setData method for your adapter. and feed it whatever data you need, so that inside of getview, you can access that data.  A checkmark would be appreciated as an answer, it is standard procedure for this site.

Comment: @hunterp Setting the data for the textviews is solved, but updating properties or methods of a component is still an issue. Not sure how to reference them. I thought a method like the following would work.  public void test(int pos)
 {
        View vi;
  vi = inflater.inflate(com.onudit.R.layout.row, null);
        ViewHolder holder;
     holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
     holder.flipper.showNext();
 }

Comment: How do I get the pretty print code to appear. Tried the <code> tag with no luck.

Comment: See there is a big empty checkmark next to the question? When you click that, it means your question has been answered. I believe that i've helped you beyond the initial scope of your question.  What do you mean by component?

Comment: "I'm having a problem updating the clicked item's views, like TextView and ViewFlipper." I agree the textview part of the question is answered. The other component (View) in the listview is the ViewFlipper which I don't know how to reference for the correct item and update. Half way there and I definitely appreciate the help you are giving.

Comment: as I said before, give all of your data in some big indexed ArrayList for example to the adapter when it is created. not just the text, but the viewflippers and whatever else. then in getView, just look it up

Comment: Sorry for the additional question. How do I push the viewflipper's into the adapter if they are created/referenced by the adapter automatically when the getView method is called. My listview adapter is set as the following.       adapter = new TitleSelectAdapter(this, title, imageUrls);
     myListView.setAdapter(adapter);  How would I go about pushing a list of viewflippers into that if the adapter finds the view when the getView method is called. Do you have an example?